# CAN anyone help me with the sp optimization?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wrote this sp. but it's taking almost 01:12 sec to execute. can anyone help me with the sp optimization?

```
declare @R71_TERM_PARA CHAR(3) = '14f'

--AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- REG-LOA
SELECT TM.*
FROM   (
        SELECT PN.UCLA_ID
              ,PN.FULL_NAME_PERSON
              ,SM.BAR_ASMT_CD
              ,SM.REG_PMT_STAT_FL
              ,SM.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD
              ,SM.JOINT_STU_FL
              ,TY.ADM_TERM_CD
              ,TD_ADM.TERM_SEQ_NUM AS ADM_TSEQ
              ,TT.TERM_CD          AS CURR_TERM
              ,TT.TERM_SEQ_NUM     AS CURR_TSEQ
              ,TT.CAREER_CD
              ,TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
              ,TT.REG_TYP_CD
              ,PT.COLL_CD
              ,PT.MAJOR_CD
              ,PT.DEG_CD
              ,PT.PROG_PRIO_FL
              ,TT_PRV1.TERM_CD         AS PRV1_TERM
              ,TT_PRV1.TERM_SEQ_NUM    AS PRV1_TSEQ
              ,TT_PRV1.REG_TYP_CD      AS PRV1_REG_TYP 
              ,SM_PRV1.REG_PMT_STAT_FL AS PRV1_PMT_FL
              ,SM_PRV1.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD  AS PRV1_WTHDRW_CD
              ,TT_PRV1.CAREER_CD       AS PRV1_CAREER
              ,TT_PRV1.CAREER_SUFX_CD  AS PRV1_SUFX
              ,TT_PRV2.TERM_CD         AS PRV2_TERM
              ,TT_PRV2.TERM_SEQ_NUM    AS PRV2_TSEQ
              ,TT_PRV2.REG_TYP_CD      AS PRV2_REG_TYP
              ,SM_PRV2.REG_PMT_STAT_FL AS PRV2_PMT_FL
              ,SM_PRV2.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD  AS PRV2_WTHDRW_CD 
              ,TT_PRV2.CAREER_CD       AS PRV2_CAREER
              ,TT_PRV2.CAREER_SUFX_CD  AS PRV2_SUFX
              ,TL.LOA_STRT_TERM_CD
              ,TL.LOA_STRT_TSEQ
              ,TL.LOA_RET_TERM_CD
              ,TL.LOA_RET_TSEQ
              ,TL.LOA_APRV_DT
              ,TL.LOA_PETN_TYP_CD
        FROM   ID0APT AS AP
               INNER JOIN
               ID0PNT AS PN
                 ON AP.UCLA_ID               = PN.UCLA_ID
                AND AP.NAME_SEQ_NUM          = PN.NAME_SEQ_NUM
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM
                 ON AP.UCLA_ID               = SM.STU_ID
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = SM.STU_ID
                AND TT.TERM_CD               = SM.TERM_CD
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0TYT AS TY
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TY.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TY.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TY.CAREER_SUFX_CD
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0PTT AS PT
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = PT.STU_ID
                AND TT.TERM_CD               = PT.TERM_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = PT.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = PT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TDT AS TD_ADM
                 ON TY.ADM_TERM_CD           = TD_ADM.TERM_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT_PRV1 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TT_PRV1.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TT_PRV1.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TT_PRV1.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                AND CASE
                     --DENTAL, GRADUATE, UNDEGRADUATE PARAMETERS
                     WHEN TT.CAREER_CD = 'D'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'G'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'U' THEN
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'F' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 3
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 1
                        END
                     --LAW, MEDICAL PARAMETERS
                     ELSE
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'F' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 3
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 2
                        END
                    END                      = TT_PRV1.TERM_SEQ_NUM    
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM_PRV1 
                 ON TT_PRV1.STU_ID           = SM_PRV1.STU_ID
                AND TT_PRV1.TERM_CD          = SM_PRV1.TERM_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT_PRV2 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TT_PRV2.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TT_PRV2.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TT_PRV2.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                AND CASE
                     --DENTAL, GRADUATE, UNDERGRADUATE PARAMETERS
                     WHEN TT.CAREER_CD = 'D'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'G'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'U' THEN
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'S' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 2
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 4
                        END
                     --LAW, MEDICAL PARAMETERS
                     ELSE              SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 5
                    END                      = TT_PRV2.TERM_SEQ_NUM    
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM_PRV2 
                 ON TT_PRV2.STU_ID           = SM_PRV2.STU_ID
                AND TT_PRV2.TERM_CD          = SM_PRV2.TERM_CD
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0TLT AS TL 
                 ON TT.STU_ID          = TL.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD       = TL.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TL.CAREER_SUFX_CD
              ,SR0TDT AS TD
        WHERE
               SM.BAR_ASMT_CD         NOT IN ('N','X')
           AND AP.APP_ID                  = 'SR0'
           AND TD.TERM_CD                 = @R71_TERM_PARA
           AND SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM           >= TD.TERM_SEQ_NUM
               --LATEST LOA START TERM BASED ON TERM VALUE
           AND TL.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  IN
                (
                 SELECT MAX(TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ)
                 FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_MAX
                 WHERE  TL_MAX.STU_ID          = TT.STU_ID
                    AND TL_MAX.CAREER_CD       = TT.CAREER_CD
                    AND TL_MAX.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                    AND TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  <= TT.TERM_SEQ_NUM
                )
               --LATEST LOA START TERM BASED ON TERM VALUE
           AND TL.LOA_APRV_DT    IN
                (
                 SELECT MAX(TL_DT.LOA_APRV_DT)
                 FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_DT
                 WHERE  TL_DT.STU_ID          = TT.STU_ID
                    AND TL_DT.CAREER_CD       = TT.CAREER_CD
                    AND TL_DT.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                    AND TL_DT.LOA_STRT_TSEQ   =
                            (
                             SELECT MAX(TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ)
                             FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_MAX
                             WHERE  TL_MAX.STU_ID          = TT.STU_ID
                                AND TL_MAX.CAREER_CD       = TT.CAREER_CD
                                AND TL_MAX.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                                AND TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  <= TT.TERM_SEQ_NUM
                            )
                )
       )      AS TM 
WHERE   --VALIDATE ONLY VALID TERMS
        (  
              (
                   TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('D','M')
               AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S','2')
              )
           OR  
              (
                   TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('G','L','U')
               AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S')
              )
        )
    AND (
            (
              (
                  (
                   --LOA MUST BE WITHIN LOA PETITION RANGE
                       TM.REG_TYP_CD                    = 'LOA'
                   AND (
                           TM.CURR_TSEQ                 > TM.LOA_RET_TSEQ
                        OR TM.BAR_ASMT_CD               = 'I'
                        OR (    TM.BAR_ASMT_CD         IN ('B','Y')
                            AND TM.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD  NOT IN ('C','X')
                           )
                        OR (
                                TM.CURR_TERM            = TM.LOA_STRT_TERM_CD
                            AND TM.PROG_PRIO_FL         = 'Y'
                           )
                       )
                  )
               OR 
                  (
                   --LOA MUST BE WITHIN LOA PETITION RANGE
                       TM.REG_TYP_CD                    <> 'LOA'
                   AND TM.CURR_TSEQ                      < TM.LOA_RET_TSEQ
                   AND TM.CURR_TSEQ                      > TM.LOA_STRT_TSEQ
                  )
               OR
                  (
                   --FILED FOR LEAVE BUT INVALID BAR_ASMT_CD
                       TM.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD                 = 'L'
                   AND TM.REG_PMT_STAT_FL                = 'N'
                   AND TM.BAR_ASMT_CD               NOT IN ('D','Z')
                  ) 
              )

            )
        OR  (
               --RLA MUST EQUAL PETITION RETURN TERM IN PREVIOUS LOA PETITION RANGE
                   TM.REG_TYP_CD                    = 'RLA'
               AND TM.CURR_TERM                 NOT IN
                     (
                      SELECT TL.LOA_RET_TERM_CD
                      FROM   SR0TLT AS TL 
                      WHERE  TL.STU_ID          = TM.UCLA_ID
                         AND TL.CAREER_CD       = TM.CAREER_CD
                         AND TL.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TM.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                         --LATEST LOA START TERM BASED ON TERM VALUE
                         AND TL.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  IN
                                (
                                 SELECT MAX(TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ)
                                 FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_MAX
                                 WHERE  TL_MAX.STU_ID          = TM.UCLA_ID
                                    AND TL_MAX.CAREER_CD       = TM.CAREER_CD
                                    AND TL_MAX.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TM.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                                    AND TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ   < TM.CURR_TSEQ
                                )
                          --VALIDATE ONLY VALID TERMS
                          AND (  
                                  (
                                       TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('D','M')
                                   AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S','2')
                                  )
                               OR  
                                  (
                                       TL.CAREER_CD          IN ('G','L','U')
                                   AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S')
                                  )
                              )
                      )
            )

        OR  (
              (
                  (
                   --RLA MUST EQUAL PETITION RETURN TERM
                       TM.REG_TYP_CD                = 'RLA'
                   AND TM.CURR_TERM                <> TM.LOA_RET_TERM_CD
                   AND TM.CURR_TSEQ                 > TM.LOA_STRT_TSEQ
                  )
                OR
                  (
                   --RLA MUST EQUAL PETITION RETURN TERM
                       TM.REG_TYP_CD               <> 'RLA'
                   AND TM.CURR_TERM                 = TM.LOA_RET_TERM_CD
                  )
              )
            )

        )

UNION

SELECT TM.*
FROM   (
        SELECT PN.UCLA_ID
              ,PN.FULL_NAME_PERSON
              ,SM.BAR_ASMT_CD
              ,SM.REG_PMT_STAT_FL
              ,SM.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD
              ,SM.JOINT_STU_FL
              ,TY.ADM_TERM_CD
              ,TD_ADM.TERM_SEQ_NUM AS ADM_TSEQ
              ,TT.TERM_CD          AS CURR_TERM
              ,TT.TERM_SEQ_NUM     AS CURR_TSEQ
              ,TT.CAREER_CD
              ,TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
              ,TT.REG_TYP_CD
              ,PT.COLL_CD
              ,PT.MAJOR_CD
              ,PT.DEG_CD
              ,PT.PROG_PRIO_FL
              ,TT_PRV1.TERM_CD         AS PRV1_TERM
              ,TT_PRV1.TERM_SEQ_NUM    AS PRV1_TSEQ
              ,TT_PRV1.REG_TYP_CD      AS PRV1_REG_TYP 
              ,SM_PRV1.REG_PMT_STAT_FL AS PRV1_PMT_FL
              ,SM_PRV1.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD  AS PRV1_WTHDRW_CD
              ,TT_PRV1.CAREER_CD       AS PRV1_CAREER
              ,TT_PRV1.CAREER_SUFX_CD  AS PRV1_SUFX
              ,TT_PRV2.TERM_CD         AS PRV2_TERM
              ,TT_PRV2.TERM_SEQ_NUM    AS PRV2_TSEQ
              ,TT_PRV2.REG_TYP_CD      AS PRV2_REG_TYP
              ,SM_PRV2.REG_PMT_STAT_FL AS PRV2_PMT_FL
              ,SM_PRV2.ENRL_WTHDRW_CD  AS PRV2_WTHDRW_CD 
              ,TT_PRV2.CAREER_CD       AS PRV2_CAREER
              ,TT_PRV2.CAREER_SUFX_CD  AS PRV2_SUFX
              ,'' AS LOA_STRT_TERM_CD
              ,0  AS LOA_STRT_TSEQ
              ,'' AS LOA_RET_TERM_CD
              ,0  AS LOA_RET_TSEQ
              ,'' AS LOA_APRV_DT
              ,'' AS LOA_PETN_TYP_CD
        FROM   ID0APT AS AP
               INNER JOIN
               ID0PNT AS PN
                 ON AP.UCLA_ID               = PN.UCLA_ID
                AND AP.NAME_SEQ_NUM          = PN.NAME_SEQ_NUM
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM
                 ON AP.UCLA_ID               = SM.STU_ID
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = SM.STU_ID
                AND TT.TERM_CD               = SM.TERM_CD
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0TYT AS TY
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TY.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TY.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TY.CAREER_SUFX_CD
               INNER JOIN 
               SR0PTT AS PT
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = PT.STU_ID
                AND TT.TERM_CD               = PT.TERM_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = PT.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = PT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TDT AS TD_ADM
                 ON TY.ADM_TERM_CD           = TD_ADM.TERM_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT_PRV1 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TT_PRV1.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TT_PRV1.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TT_PRV1.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                AND CASE
                     --DENTAL, GRADUATE, UNDEGRADUATE PARAMETERS
                     WHEN TT.CAREER_CD = 'D'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'G'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'U' THEN
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'F' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 3
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 1
                        END
                     --LAW, MEDICAL PARAMETERS
                     ELSE
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'F' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 3
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 2
                        END
                    END                      = TT_PRV1.TERM_SEQ_NUM    
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM_PRV1 
                 ON TT_PRV1.STU_ID           = SM_PRV1.STU_ID
                AND TT_PRV1.TERM_CD          = SM_PRV1.TERM_CD
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0TTT AS TT_PRV2 
                 ON TT.STU_ID                = TT_PRV2.STU_ID
                AND TT.CAREER_CD             = TT_PRV2.CAREER_CD
                AND TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD        = TT_PRV2.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                AND CASE
                     --DENTAL, GRADUATE, UNDERGRADUATE PARAMETERS
                     WHEN TT.CAREER_CD = 'D'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'G'
                       OR TT.CAREER_CD = 'U' THEN
                        CASE RIGHT(SM.TERM_CD,1)
                         WHEN 'S' THEN SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 2
                         ELSE          SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 4
                        END
                     --LAW, MEDICAL PARAMETERS
                     ELSE              SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM - 5
                    END                      = TT_PRV2.TERM_SEQ_NUM    
               LEFT JOIN 
               SR0SMT AS SM_PRV2 
                 ON TT_PRV2.STU_ID           = SM_PRV2.STU_ID
                AND TT_PRV2.TERM_CD          = SM_PRV2.TERM_CD
              ,SR0TDT AS TD
        WHERE
               SM.BAR_ASMT_CD         NOT IN ('N','X')
           AND AP.APP_ID                  = 'SR0'
           AND TD.TERM_CD                 = @R71_TERM_PARA
           AND SM.TERM_SEQ_NUM           >= TD.TERM_SEQ_NUM
       )      AS TM 
WHERE   --LOA AND RLA MUST HAVE A VALID PETIION RANGE
        TM.REG_TYP_CD         IN ('LOA','RLA')
    AND TM.UCLA_ID        NOT IN
         (
          SELECT TL.STU_ID
          FROM   SR0TLT AS TL 
          WHERE  TL.STU_ID          = TM.UCLA_ID
             AND TL.CAREER_CD       = TM.CAREER_CD
             AND TL.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TM.CAREER_SUFX_CD
             --LATEST LOA START TERM BASED ON TERM VALUE
             AND TL.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  IN
                    (
                     SELECT MAX(TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ)
                     FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_MAX
                     WHERE  TL_MAX.STU_ID          = TM.UCLA_ID
                        AND TL_MAX.CAREER_CD       = TM.CAREER_CD
                        AND TL_MAX.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TM.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                        AND TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ   < TM.CURR_TSEQ
                    )
              --VALIDATE ONLY VALID TERMS
              AND (  
                      (
                           TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('D','M')
                       AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S','2')
                      )
                   OR  
                      (
                           TL.CAREER_CD          IN ('G','L','U')
                       AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S')
                      )
                  )
          )


ORDER BY UCLA_ID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'WARNING: NO ROWS WERE SELECTED.';

END
```

I think there is similar code in the second union . Is there any possibility to add this code into CTE and then joining where ever needed ?

Comment: OMG, that's like 400 lines of SQL with gobs of joins and case statements.  I would start by breaking it into pieces and seeing if any of them performs badly, then start joining it back together if it's not one of them separately.  We're not going to be able to help with this w/o your schema for all the tables and index definitions.

Comment: "UNDEGRADUATE"? Have you checked the execution plan? Updated the statistics? Considered using materialized views? Based on your description of the environment and size of the tables involved we have no reason to believe that the performance is not superb.

Answer (score 0):

Find out if the top half and the bottom half are mutually exclusive. If they are, change the "union" to "union all". Also, do the end results need to be ordered by UCLA_ID? If not, take that out.

Then unfortunately, you're going to have to start with one half, starting with the inner subquery/derived table, then start with a table. My guess from trying to read the first half is to start with

```
select top 1 *
from ID0APT AS AP
where
AP.APP_ID = 'SR0';
```

Make sure that returns immediately. Then, you add in the join to the next table, along with any corresponding "where". See if you can get through all of the joins without suffering a major slowdown trying to pull the first record.

If you do find a slow down, make sure you have an index in place to satisfy your composite joins.

Then you can try adding in the complicated "in"'s at the bottom, e.g.

```
--LATEST LOA START TERM BASED ON TERM VALUE
       AND TL.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  IN
            (
             SELECT MAX(TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ)
             FROM   SR0TLT AS TL_MAX
             WHERE  TL_MAX.STU_ID          = TT.STU_ID
                AND TL_MAX.CAREER_CD       = TT.CAREER_CD
                AND TL_MAX.CAREER_SUFX_CD  = TT.CAREER_SUFX_CD
                AND TL_MAX.LOA_STRT_TSEQ  <= TT.TERM_SEQ_NUM
            )
```

These are correlated subqueries, that I think are going to be the start of your problems.

Then you can look at the complicated "OR"'s, e.g.

```
WHERE   --VALIDATE ONLY VALID TERMS
        (  
              (
                   TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('D','M')
               AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S','2')
              )
           OR  
              (
                   TM.CAREER_CD          IN ('G','L','U')
               AND RIGHT(TM.CURR_TERM,1) IN ('F','W','S')
              )
        )
```